# ClosureParams: how to specify generic types for closure parameter in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, closures

I have the following method in Java:

```
public void myMethod(
        @ClosureParams(
                value = SimpleType.class,
                options = {
                        "java.util.Map"
                }
        ) Closure<String> closure
) {
    ...
}
```

which has `@ClosureParams` to specify closure's parameter types for static type checker and type inference in IDEA.

In the Groovy script, I call this method as follows:

```
myMethod { Map<String, Object> doc ->
    ...
}
```

and it works fine. But when I try to specify **generic types** for `java.util.Map` of closure in my java method:

```
public void myMethod(
        @ClosureParams(
                value = SimpleType.class,
                options = {
                        "java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>" // <-- added here
                }
        ) Closure<String> closure
) {
    ...
}
```

groovy's static type checker fails with error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\myproject\script.groovy: 1: Expected parameter of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> but got java.util.Map <String, Object>
 @ line 1, column 8.
myMethod { Map<String, Object> doc ->
```

although IDEA infers the type of `doc` without any `Map` or `Map<...>` using `@ClosureParams` hint.

When I look into the source of `groovy.transform.stc.SimpleType` class, I see that this class does not give the ability to specify generic types as it uses plain `Class.forName`:

```
public class SimpleType extends SingleSignatureClosureHint {
    @Override
    public ClassNode[] getParameterTypes(final MethodNode node, final String[] options, final SourceUnit sourceUnit, final CompilationUnit unit, final ASTNode usage) {
        ClassNode[] result = new ClassNode[options.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = findClassNode(sourceUnit, unit, options[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
 }

    // findClassNode method:
    protected ClassNode findClassNode(final SourceUnit sourceUnit, final CompilationUnit compilationUnit, final String className) {
        if (className.endsWith("[]")) {
            return findClassNode(sourceUnit, compilationUnit, className.substring(0, className.length() - 2)).makeArray();
        }
        ClassNode cn = compilationUnit.getClassNode(className);
        if (cn == null) {
            try {
                cn = ClassHelper.make(Class.forName(className, false, sourceUnit.getClassLoader()));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                cn = ClassHelper.make(className);
            }
        }
        return cn;
    }
```

**My question:** how to specify closure parameter type with generics in groovy? Preferably with support in IDEA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `groovy.transform.stc.FromString` signature hint to get the generic types working. Consider the following example:

*JavaClass.java*

```java
import groovy.lang.Closure;
import groovy.transform.stc.ClosureParams;
import groovy.transform.stc.FromString;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class JavaClass {

    public static void processRendered(@ClosureParams(
            value = FromString.class,
            options = {"java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>"}) Closure closure) {

        closure.call(new HashMap<String, Object>());
    }
}
```

*script.groovy*

```groovy
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import static JavaClass.processRendered

@CompileStatic
def test() {
  processRendered { Map<String, Object> map ->
    map.put("test", 1)
  }

  processRendered {
    it.put("test", 2)
  }
}

test()
```

It compiles and gives you signature hint, also for the implicit `it` variable.

[image]

The following example uses Groovy **2.5.7**.

Comment: Which version of IDEA you use?

Comment: @cybersoft IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.6 (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: Hmm.. I'm running on 2018.3.3 UE and it complains "cannot infer types" :( My closure has two parameters, but I think it does not matter. Will try to update IDEA...

Comment: @cybersoft I checked the signature hint for two parameters like `java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>, java.lang.String`, worked without an issue. Also, I have updated my IntelliJ IDEA to the 2019.1.3 - works in this version as well. One hint regarding updating IDEA - "Update and Restart" broke my 2018.3.6 (I couldn't open any source file) and I had to install 2019.1.3 manually.

Comment: Single parameter works fine but when I specify `options = {"java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>","java.lang.String"}`, IDE stops infer types; also updated to 2019.1.3

Comment: For two parameters define `options = {"java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>, java.lang.String"}` in a single string. Then `processRenderred { m, s -> .... }` will infer types for `m` and `s` correctly.

Comment: Yes, you are right, now it works. Javadoc mentions this: `where each string corresponds to a single signature` but I thouhgt it works like with `SimpleType`. In general, groovy doc is not so detailed about such things. Thank you very much! Sorry my for bad english.